# What is the difference between \paperheight, \paperwidth and \pdfpageheight, \pdfpagewidth?

Tags: tex-core, latex-base

I couldn't find any existing answers to this question.

So, what's the difference? Are there any advantages to using one duo over the other?

Comment: Please tell us which TeX engine you use: pdfTeX, XeTeX, or LuaTeX?

Comment: @Mico sorry for the late response - i had no idea so i had to check. it's PdfLaTeX.

Answer (score 12):

`\pdfpageheight` was introduced by `pdftex` (and it prefixes most of its "new" commands with `\pdf`) It sets the vertical size of the mediabox in the resulting PDF.  xetex also supports this primitive and passes the information to the xdvipdfmx dvi driver. luatex has a command with identical functionality but it is called `\pageheight`.

LaTeX has a command `\paperheight` that is usually set with documentclass options such as `a4paper` it is used mainly for adjusting the size of the text block, e.g. `\textheight` is `\paperheight` minus some space for top and bottom margins. If packages that "know" about driver-specific code (`graphics`, `hyperref`, `geometry`) are loaded then by default `\(pdf)pageheight` will be set based on the value of `\paperheight` by the package code.

So, setting `\paperheight` in the preamble will normally have no effect at all, as the value has already been used to set `\textheight` and changing it has no effect. The exception, as noted above is if a package uses the value of `\paperheight` in the preamble to set `\(pdf)pageheight` at `\begin{document}`.  Conversely setting `\(pdf)pageheight` has an immediate effect of changing the dimensions of the generated PDF, although again if a package re-sets the value at `\begin{document}` then the value you set directly may not be used.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, there's a big difference between `\paperheight` and `\paperwidth` on the one hand and `\pdfpageheight` and `\pdfpagewidth` on the other. The differences are engine-specific:

- With pdfLaTeX, all four macros are defined. However, whether or not `\paperheight` and `\pdfpageheight` (and `\paperwidth` and `\pdfpagewidth`) coincide depends on your system settings. E.g., my MacOS-based computer is currently configured to treat `A4` as the "standard" paper size. But if I run

  ```
  \documentclass[letterpaper]{article} % letterpaper: 8.5" wide, 11.0" tall
  \begin{document}
  \obeylines
  \the\paperheight
  \the\pdfpageheight 
  \the\paperwidth
  \the\pdfpagewidth
  \end{document}
  ```

  through pdfLaTeX, I get `794.96999pt` and `614.295pt` -- the equivalent of 11" and 8.5" -- for `\paperheight` and `\paperwidth`. However, I get `845.04684pt` and `597.50787pt` -- the equivalent of 297mm and 210mm, or 11.69" and 8.27" -- for `\pdfpageheight` and `\pdfpagewidth`, respectively. (Aside: 297mm and 210mm are the correct values for A4 paper.) Put differently, selecting the document class option `letterpaper` managed to change the values of `\paperheight` and `\paperwidth`, but not those of `\pdfpageheight` and `\pdfpagewidth`.
- Under XeLaTeX, the macros `\pdfpagewidth` and `\pdfpageheight` both exist, but they are both set to `0pt` by default. The values of `\paperheight` and `\paperwidth` both depend on whether `a4paper` or `letterpaper` is provided as a documentclass-level option.
- Under LuaLaTeX, `\pdfpagewidth` and `\pdfpageheight` are, by default, both *undefined*. The values of `\pagewidth` and `\pageheight` will either coincide or differ from `\paperwidth` and `\paperheight` depending on whether your system settings coincide with the paper-size option (`a4paper` or `letterpaper`) you specify at the document class level.

  The values of `\paperheight` and `\paperwidth` both depend on whether `a4paper` or `letterpaper` is provided as a documentclass-level option.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to read or to write those dimensions?

In PdfLatex and XeLatex changing `\pdfpageheight` and `\pdfpagewidth` will actually change the document page size beginning with the current page. In LuaLatex you have to use `\pageheight` and `\pagewidth` i.e. without `pdf`.

`\paperheight` and `\paperwidth` seem to be copies or preliminary variables for the real ones. Which package/option/macro reads or sets which during what is better explained in the other answers.—Having two pairs might make sense if you want margins etc. to be calculated having different paper dimensions in mind than the actual output area. Maybe.

By the way, only the PDF path allows mid-document changes. DVI and Postscript do not support this.