# Default font sizes do not work with new paper size option

Tags: document-classes, class-options

I wonder why the default font sizes won't work in the following modified class file.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{example.cls}
\ProvidesClass{example}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1996/06/01]%           
\LoadClass{article}
\DeclareOption{folio}{
    \setlength{\paperheight}{330.2mm}%
    \setlength{\paperwidth}{215.9mm}%
}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass
%[10pt]
%[11pt, folio]
[12pt,folio]
{example} 
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum  
\end{document}
```

I tried the suggestion in [How to set default font size in latex cls file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40893/how-to-set-default-font-size-in-latex-cls-file)

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{example.cls}
\ProvidesClass{example}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1996/06/01]%           


\def\@@ptsize{12pt}
\DeclareOption{10pt}{\def\@@ptsize{10pt}}
\DeclareOption{11pt}{\def\@@ptsize{11pt}}
\DeclareOption{12pt}{\def\@@ptsize{12pt}}
\LoadClass[\@@ptsize]{article}
\DeclareOption{folio}{
    \setlength{\paperheight}{330.2mm}%
    \setlength{\paperwidth}{215.9mm}%
}

\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\end{filecontents}

\documentclass
%[10pt]
%[11pt, folio]
[10pt,folio]
{example} 
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum  
\end{document}
```

but I get an error.

> ! LaTeX Error: \RequirePackage or \LoadClass in Options Section.

I tried putting all `\DeclareOption`s after the `\LoadClass` command but I am not seeing any effect in the document.

### Edit

I should have mentioned that putting `\LoadClass` after `\ProcessOptions`, as in the answer by Werner has the effect of the paper size `folio` option not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load the class only *after* you've processed the options:

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{example.cls}
\ProvidesClass{example}
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\DeclareOption{folio}{%
  \setlength{\paperheight}{330.2mm}%
  \setlength{\paperwidth}{215.9mm}%
}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions
\LoadClass{article}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass
  [12pt,folio]
  {example} 
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum  
\end{document}
```

Comment: This has the effect of the paper size option not working though. I am sorry that I missed that part in my question. I should edit it now.

Comment: @hpesoj626: Changes *are* applied to `\paperheight` and `\paperwidth`. However, if your plan is to change the page dimensions, they won't have any effect in the preamble. See [What is the difference between `\paperheight`, `\paperwidth` and `\pdfpageheight`, `\pdfpagewidth`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/425643/5764) Instead, you should try to set `\pdfpagewidth` and `\pdfpageheight` if you're using pdfLaTeX.

Comment: That resolved the problem. Thank you for your answer and your link!