# Why I cant see the Hebrew titles?

Tags: fonts, fontspec, font-encodings, hebrew, bidi

I'm trying to write a document that contains English, so I put:

```
\begin{english}
 % Some lines....
\end{english}
```

And then, if I put TOC at the beginning, this is the result:
[image]

No titles of parts, sections,...

If I'm removing the TOC or the `english` part - it works, but not with both :-(
Do you know why and how can I solve it?

MWE:

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.3.6.1 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[a4paper,english,hebrew,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\parindent}{0bp}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0},pdfborderstyle={},backref=false,colorlinks=true]
 {hyperref}
\hypersetup{
 linkcolor=blue}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
\pdfpageheight\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{David CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfonttt[Script=Hebrew]{Miriam Mono CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf[Script=Hebrew]{Bellefair}
\AtBeginDocument{
\renewcommand\footnoterule{%
  \kern -3pt
  \hbox to \textwidth{\hfill\vrule height 0.4pt width .4\textwidth}
  \kern 2.6pt
}}


% Commands:


\makeatother

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents{}

\part{שלום}

\section{שלום}

\begin{english}
abcd
\end{english}
\end{document}
```

*P.S. I tried to change the font to `FreeSans` and although this - the titles are still missing*

Thank you!

Comment: Works OK in Lualatex in TexLive2020 (without the two LyX commands, and using FreeSans font).

Comment: What do you get when you add `\tracinglostchars=3`, to make it an error when you try to use characters the font does not have?

Answer (score 1):

Using the font Arial and

```
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Arial}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfonttt[Script=Hebrew]{Arial}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf[Script=Hebrew]{Arial}
```

I get the same result.

But with

```
\setmainfont{Arial}
\setmonofont{Arial}
\setsansfont{Arial}
```

the result is fine

[image: a]

(I am using TeXstudio, so I removed the LyX specific LaTeX commands. They are not needed with xelatex or lualatex. They will be set by the `a4paper` of the class. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/425649/161015 )

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,english,hebrew,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsthm}
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0bp}
    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage{pifont}
    \usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
    bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
    breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0},pdfborderstyle={},backref=false,colorlinks=true]
    {hyperref}
    \hypersetup{
        linkcolor=blue}
    
    \makeatletter
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
    %\pdfpageheight\paperheight
    %\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth
    
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
    %\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{DavidCLM}
    %\newfontfamily\hebrewfonttt[Script=Hebrew]{Miriam Mono CLM}
    %\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf[Script=Hebrew]{Bellefair}
    
    
    %% IT DOES NOT WORK
    %\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Arial}
    %\newfontfamily\hebrewfonttt[Script=Hebrew]{Arial}
    %\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf[Script=Hebrew]{Arial}
    
    
    % THIS WORKS OK ! <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \setmainfont{Arial}
    \setmonofont{Arial}
    \setsansfont{Arial}
    
    \AtBeginDocument{
        \renewcommand\footnoterule{%
            \kern -3pt
            \hbox to \textwidth{\hfill\vrule height 0.4pt width .4\textwidth}
            \kern 2.6pt
    }}  
    % Commands:
    
    \makeatother
    
    \usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
    \setotherlanguage{english}
    
    \begin{document}
        \tableofcontents{}
        
        \part{שלום}
        
        \section{שלום}
        
        \begin{english}
            abcd
        \end{english}
    \end{document}
```

**Using other fonts**. In this example the `.ttf` files in sub-directories under the directory FONTS of the working directory.

[image: d]

[image: b]

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex 

\documentclass[a4paper,english,hebrew,numbers=noenddot]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\parindent}{0bp}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0},pdfborderstyle={},backref=false,colorlinks=true]
{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    linkcolor=blue}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}  

% using other fonts. .ttf files in subdirectories under the directory FONTS of the working directory <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\setmainfont[
Path =./FONTS/TaameyDavidCLM/,
Ligatures = TeX ,
Script = Hebrew,
Extension=.ttf,
UprightFont=*-Medium ,
BoldFont=*-Bold,
ItalicFont=*-MediumOblique,
BoldItalicFont=*-BoldOblique,
Scale=1.0      % Adjust to match Latin font
]{TaameyDavidCLM}

\setmonofont[
Path =./FONTS/MiriamMonoCLM/,
Script = Hebrew,
Extension=.ttf,
UprightFont=*-Book,
BoldFont=*-Bold,
ItalicFont=*-BookOblique,
BoldItalicFont=*-BoldOblique,
Scale=1.0      % Adjust to match Latin font
]{MiriamMonoCLM}    

\setsansfont[
Path =./FONTS/DejaVuSans/,
Ligatures = TeX ,
Script = Hebrew,
Extension=.ttf,
UprightFont=* ,
BoldFont=*-Bold,
ItalicFont=*-Oblique,
BoldItalicFont=*-BoldOblique,
Scale=1.0      % Adjust to match Latin font
]{DejaVuSans}


\AtBeginDocument{
    \renewcommand\footnoterule{%
        \kern -3pt
        \hbox to \textwidth{\hfill\vrule height 0.4pt width .4\textwidth}
        \kern 2.6pt
}}  

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents        
    
    \part{שלום}
    
    \section{שלום}
    
    \begin{english}
        abcd
    \end{english}

\section{בראשית}
\textbf{בְּרֵאשִׁ֖ית}
\textit{יְהִ֣י א֑וֹר}


\bigskip 

\texttt{ \textbf{וַיַּ֧רְא אֱלֹהִ֛ים אֶת־הָא֖וֹר כִּי־ט֑וֹב וַיַּבְדֵּ֣ל אֱלֹהִ֔ים בֵּ֥ין} הָא֖וֹר וּבֵ֥ין הַחֹֽשֶׁךְ׃ }

\section{מבוא}
זוהי עובדה מבוססת שדעתו של הקורא תהיה מוסחת עלידי טקטס קריא כאשר הוא יביט בפריסתו.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! But if I want to use other fonts then Arial, this is possible? "Remove the LyX specific LaTeX commands" - what do you mean?

Comment: @heblyx What fonts do you want to use? I am using TeXstudio so I deleted `\pdfpageheight\paperheight` and `\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth`. They are not needed. The pdf will follow the a4paper option.

Comment: It gives me error because the path of the fonts, how can I find mine? (When I add the lines: \setsansfont[
Path =./FONTS/DejaVuSans/, ...)

Comment: @heblyx To run this example as it is: Make a directory `FONTS` in your working directory (where you have the example). Then underneath create a subdirectory `DejaVuSans`. Put in it the four `.ttf` files, as shown in the second figure.

You can download the files from https://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/dejavu.zip (subdirectory `truetype)`.

Comment: @heblyx In a similar way for `TaameyDavidCLM` font  from http://culmus.sourceforge.net/taamim/TaameyDavidCLM.zip. Other hebrew fonts can be found in the culmus project http://culmus.sourceforge.net/index.html

Comment: Still don't working :-\