# Undefined control sequence <argument> \pdfpagewidth

Tags: graphics, luatex

I want to switch from PDFLaTeX to LuaLaTeX to use OpenType Fonts. When I switched my compiler I got lots of errors, the first one beeing:

```
Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \pdfpagewidth 
              
l.5 \begin{document}
```

This is what Overleaf has to say to this issue:

```
The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used.
Check that the command is spelled correctly.
If the command is part of a package,
make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.
```

And here is a corresponding minimal working example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

Comment: LuaTeX renames a number of primitives, including `\pdfpagewidth`. However, before we try to 'fix' that, can you give a full [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that)? For end user documents, the primitives shouldn't normally show up at all, and package code 'knows' about these differences in the main.

Comment: that is a pdftex primitive that shouldn't normally be set directly, but see the luatex manual for equivalents, or use luatex85 package to define many such pdftex commands

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undefined control sequence setting PDF geometry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/691097/undefined-control-sequence-setting-pdf-geometry)

Comment: Also related (but only the main reason and the answers, `standalone` like most packages does not have this problem any longer): https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/315025/277964

Comment: Voters: proposed dupe _isn't_ about `\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}`.

Comment: Well it may describes the command, but this is not a solution suitable for me. The error was with the import of graphicx, from which I don't see anything in the proposed question

Comment: @JosephWright Sorry, but without MWE and any information in the question, that this happens when loading `graphicx`, I really wasn't able to guess, that loading `graphicx` with a (generally superfluous and now) unsuitable option was the mistake.

Comment: @cabohah Sure, but the self-answer clears that up .. anyway, I'm sure there must be an appropriate dupe

Comment: @JosephWright My guess was *before* the self-answer.

Comment: I've now added all information that is IMHO needed. So the answer is also suitable and if there really isn't already a dupe (which I almost cannot believe, but I didn't find any) this question and answer can be useful for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was when importing `graphicx`.
In pdftex the template I used used `\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}` to import `graphicx`. After removing `pdftex` like this `\usepackage{graphicx}`, the error disappeared.

Comment: Glad you found the culprit. It would have been helpful to include the piece of information about loading the `graphicx` package with the option `pdftex` in your posting.

Comment: @Mico I didn't know it was there. I am using a template and have like 40 imports from which I understand maybe 5 (exaggerated). If I would known this, I would have tried it before. Also Latex didn't care to have any information on where the error was, beside `\begin{document}` so no luck there either.